# Dynamically styling external library

Tags: angular

My component loads an external library which generates some fancy HTML inside the template. Illustration:

```ts
@Component({
template: `<div #container></div>`, 
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
export class App {
    @ViewChild("container") container_ref;
    dynamic_height = "50 px";
    ngOnInit() {
        The_library.insert_html_square_inside_of(this.container_ref.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

The library puts a `<div id="square"/>` inside the container. How do I make this square div's height dynamically dependent from my `dynamic_height` variable? If it were simple template code, I could just do `<div [style.height]="dynamic_height">`. But the html is comes from the libarary, so this is not feasible.

My ideas so far:

- In the styles: `#square { height: {{dynamic_height}} }`. No error but Angular does not parse this, thus obviously invalid property value.
- In template: `template: "<style>#square{ height: {{dynamic_height}} }</style>"`. Same
- Hooking into changes of `dynamic_height` (ngOnChanges) and updating the height manually using `document.getElementById("square").style.height = dynamic_height`. Might work, but is probably the wrong approach.

Here is a plunker with sample code, if desired. https://embed.plnkr.co/M46XfP/

(real world use case: setting group height of `vis` timeline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by creating another div which would contain the `<style>` tag in the template :

```
<div id="container" #container></div>
<div id="styleContainer" #styleContainer></div>
```

Then in app.component.ts, you use the decorator `@ViewChild` for *#styleContainer* and you insert the HTML this way :

```
export class App {
  @ViewChild("container") container_ref;
  @ViewChild("styleContainer") style_container;
  dynamic_height = '50px';
  ngOnInit() {
    render_something(this.container_ref.nativeElement);
    this.updateStyle(this.dynamic_height);
  }
}
```

Each time you want to change the style you call updateStyle() and it will replace the `<style>` tag in the container.

```
updateStyle(height: string) {
    this.style_container.nativeElement.innerHTML =
    `<style>#square {height: `+height+` !important; }</style>`;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't update itself on property change, but this is a wicked idea

Comment: I edited my answer with a solution to update the property, it might not be the best one, but it worked! The code can be simplified by calling the updateStyle method in ngOnInit and giving the height as a parameter